# Why font dont work from this tutorial, any solutions?

Tags: text, fonts, game-engine, sfml

So, i'm writing game from this tutorial and i'm on fonts and text:
https://youtu.be/xWdfKcNeqnY
And fonts doesnt work. I wrote the same thing as he and it doesnt work. Any solution?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: There are lots of reasons why a font might not work, way too many for us to guess. I would read through the official tutorial for Texts and Fonts, and follow each step. The official tutorial states at each step what problems can occur. They also provide a minimal example you can run for yourself in your own program. Use this as the basis for figuring out what problem you have, what is different between it and your current code. You can find the official tutorial for Text and Fonts at https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/latest/graphics-text.php